# Правильно ли реализовано решение?

Tags: c++, безопасность, c++14

имеется задание:

> Решить задачу, используя общий сегмент памяти. Для это необходимо написать 2 программы:
>
> 1. решает задачу и помещает результат в общий сегмент памяти;
> 2. читает информацию из общего сегмента памяти и выводит её на экран.

Задача:

> Вводятся целые числа a и b. Пусть у треугольника ABC координаты A=(0,0), B=(a,b),
> а обе координаты C=(x,y) - целые числа, и площадь треугольника ABC не равна нулю.
> Какую минимальную площадь может иметь треугольник ABC?

Верно, ли я начал данную задачу решать?

```
#include <iostream>

/*
По заданным координатам трех вершин мы можем найти площадь треугольника ABC
Sabc=(bx-ay)/2

Если a=0, то минимальная площадь Smin=b/2, если b=0, то Smin=a/2.
Если же обе координаты отличны от нуля, то из алгоритма Евклида для нахождения НОД(a,b)=(a,b),
следует существование таких целых x и y, что ABS(bx-ay)=(a,b),
и именно эти x и y минимизируют площадь треугольника ABC.
*/


int gcd(int a, int b) {
  if (b == 0) return a;
  else return gcd(b, a % b);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << gcd(2, 1) * 0.5 << std::endl;
}
```